# how to configure logstash with elasticsearch for window?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am struggling to configure and use logstash with elasticsearch. I downloaded the logstash-1.2.0-flatjar.jar, and created the `sample.conf` with content

```
input { stdin { type => "stdin-type"}}

output { stdout {}
elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

and tried to run `java -jar logstash-1.2.0-flatjar.jar agent -f sample.conf` which produces

```
{:fix_jar_path=>["jar:file:/C:/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/Toshiba/logstach-jar/logstash-1.2.0-flatjar.jar!/locales/en.yml"]}
log4j, [2014-04-02T22:39:28.121]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast: [Chimera] failed to send ping to [[#zen_unicast_1#][inet[localho
st/127.0.0.1:9300]]]
```

Could anyone please help? Do i need to install plugins? Please provide the link
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the embedded elasticsearch in logstash, you can try to download elasticsearch and start the elasticsearch as a different instance. Please refer to this [page](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.0/tutorials/getting-started-centralized) about how to setup an elasticsearch